# Yii Post запрос на текущую страницу?

Tags: yii

в пхп постоянно пользовался пост запросами. а в yii чет все идет через контроллеры, аякс и прочее.
как мона реализовать следующее

```
<form id="newForm"  method="post">
<input type="submit" name="ex" value="Excel" onclick="document.getElementById("newForm").submit()">
```

```
if(isset($_POST["ex"])) 
    {
      header('Content-Type: text/x-csv; charset=utf-8');
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=".date("d-m-Y")."-export.xls");
      header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Yii (если не делать все совсем по фен-шую) на самом деле все будет мало чем отличаться:

```
public function actionSomething()
{
    if (Yii::app()->request->getPost('ex')) {
        // обработка
    }
    // вывод формы
}
```

По фен-шую это необходимо разделить на два отдельных экшена и настроить их разделение по одному URL через роутинг (для GET-запросов один, для POST-запросов другой). В этом случае надо будет все-таки переделать форму, вставив туда генерацию ссылки (в этом случае роутинг может быть безболезненно изменен), а также добавить редирект в конец POST-экшена.

P.S. onclick не нужен вообще,он репродуцирует текущее поведение формы.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно просто проверить тип запроса, то:

```
if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
{
   ...
}
if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
{
   ...
}
```

Для получения данных из POST или GET (в любом существующем):

```
$name = Yii::app()->request->getParam('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

в общем то вот решение. просто не сразу понял что к чему

http://yiiframework.ru/doc/cookbook/ru/js.ajax